# Normalize sql string combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Fruits
( 

    Fruits VARCHAR(100)
) 

INSERT INTO #Fruits (Fruits)
VALUES ( 'banana,apple'),
       ('apple,banana'),
       ('kiwi,jackfruit'),
       ('jackfruit, kiwi')


banana,apple
apple,banana
kiwi,jackfruit
jackfruit, kiwi
```

I want to add one more column where I am taking the values separated by comma in each row and rearrange them alphabetically. I am trying to normalize the values because for my purpose **apple,banana** & **banana,apple** are the same things. And **kiwi,jackfruit** & **jackfruit,kiwi** are the same things. The output should look like the following:

```
Fruits                Normalized_Fruits
banana,apple          apple,banana
apple,banana          apple,banana
kiwi,jackfruit        jackfruit, kiwi
jackfruit, kiwi       jackfruit, kiwi
```

How can I accomplish the desired result?

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store lists of things in a delimited string.

Comment: You are struggling here because you are storing delimited data. This violates 1NF and is nothing but painful. Any chance you can normalize your data and stop storing delimited information like this? If not, you have to first split your strings on comma, then order those string and finally reassemble them.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Unfortunately, I have no control over they way the data is stored.

Comment: @SeanLange Unfortunately, I have no control over they way the data is stored. I am trying to accomplish step 2 and 3("order those string and finally reassemble them")

Comment: Sounds like homework...

Comment: Use the String_Split (Sql 2016+) function to table them and then join them back sorted with a comma between them.

Comment: @WEI_DBA  Thank you Wei. Would you consider posting your thoughts as an answer?

Comment: Asides: You might want to consider _normalizing_ while you are "normalizing", e.g. add tables for _words_ and _word occurrences_. That should make queries like _ugli and quince and not kumquat_ rather more practical. It's also good practice to include a _question_, preferably specific, when posting a "question" on SO.

Comment: @HABO I will try to make the question more specific. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of my biggest complaints about string_split is it lacks the ordinal position of each value. That makes situations like this one a lot easier to work with. Here is another approach to this. I am using the splitter from Jeff Moden which can be found [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/). There really is no need for a cursor here.

I also took the liberty of adding a GroupID column so you know which row each value belongs to once you parse them out. If the Fruits column is unique you could skip that but hard to tell for sure.

```
CREATE TABLE #Fruits
( 
    GroupID int identity
    , Fruits VARCHAR(100)
) 

INSERT INTO #Fruits (Fruits)
VALUES ( 'banana,apple'),
       ('apple,banana'),
       ('kiwi,jackfruit'),
       ('jackfruit, kiwi')

;
with SortedResults as
(
    select f.GroupID
        , Item = ltrim(x.Item)
        , x.ItemNumber
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by GroupID order by ltrim(x.Item))
    from #Fruits f
    cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(f.Fruits, ',') x
)

select Max(case when RowNum = 1 then Item end) + ', ' + max(case when RowNum = 2 then Item end)
from SortedResults
group by GroupID

drop table #Fruits
```

Comment: Great solution! Beginning to realize the difficulty of coming up with  elegant solutions  when the way data is stored violates sql principles in a blatant way.

Comment: Dang it Sean... :-) I keep forgetting about `Row_Number() over Partition`. Nice work! +1

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot... I'm probably going to get nailed by non-Cursor folks, but this is what I came up with.

```
    CREATE TABLE #Fruits
( 

    Fruits VARCHAR(100)
) 

INSERT INTO #Fruits (Fruits)
VALUES ( 'banana,apple'),
       ('apple,banana'),
       ('kiwi,jackfruit'),
       ('jackfruit, kiwi')


Declare @tblFruit Table (Fruit1 varchar(100))
Declare @tblFruitSorted Table (FruitSorted varchar(100))

Declare fCursor Cursor For
Select Fruits From #Fruits

Declare @Fruitunsorted varchar(100), @FruitSorted Varchar(100) = ''

Open fCursor

Fetch Next From fCursor Into @Fruitunsorted

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

Set @FruitSorted = ''

Insert Into @tblFruit
Select * From string_split(@Fruitunsorted,',')

Update @tblFruit Set Fruit1 = Ltrim(Rtrim(Fruit1))

Select @FruitSorted = @FruitSorted + ',' + Ltrim(Rtrim(Fruit1)) From @tblFruit Order by Fruit1

Delete From @tblFruit

Insert Into @tblFruitSorted
Select Substring(@FruitSorted,2, LEN(@FruitSorted)-1)

Fetch Next From fCursor into @Fruitunsorted
END

Close fCursor
Deallocate fCursor

Select * From @tblFruitSorted

Drop Table #Fruits
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL 2017 or higher:

```
SELECT f.Fruits
    ,STRING_AGG(RTRIM(LTRIM(s.[value])),',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RTRIM(LTRIM(s.[value])))
FROM #Fruits f CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(f.Fruits,',') s
GROUP BY f.Fruits
;
```

If you're using older versions of SQL (like 2008):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Fruits') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Fruits;
CREATE TABLE #Fruits(Fruits VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO #Fruits (Fruits) VALUES 
    ('banana,apple'),
    ('apple,banana'),
    ('kiwi,jackfruit'),
    ('jackfruit, kiwi')
;

;WITH Split AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT a.Fruits,RTRIM(LTRIM(tbl.col.value ('@Value', 'nvarchar(max)'))) AS [Fruit]
    FROM (SELECT f.Fruits,CONVERT(XML,'<N Value="' + REPLACE(f.Fruits,',','"></N><N Value="') + '"></N>') AS [x] FROM #Fruits f) a
    CROSS APPLY a.x.nodes('//N') AS tbl (col)
)
SELECT r.Fruits,STUFF((SELECT ',' + s.Fruit FROM Split s WHERE s.Fruits = r.Fruits ORDER BY s.Fruit FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS [NormalizedFruits]
FROM #Fruits r
;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Fruits') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Fruits;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since we're only talking about a comma delimited list of two purely alphabetic strings, I'll just throw out PARSENAME again for fun and conciseness. The trims are there because of the inconsistent use of spaces in the source data and the `ELSE` could be shorter, but I wanted the results to be consistent.

```
SELECT 
    Fruits
    ,CASE 
        WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(PARSENAME(REPLACE(Fruits,',','.'),2))) > LTRIM(RTRIM(PARSENAME(REPLACE(Fruits,',','.'),1)))
        THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(PARSENAME(REPLACE(Fruits,',','.'),1))) + ', ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(PARSENAME(REPLACE(Fruits,',','.'),2)))
        ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(PARSENAME(REPLACE(Fruits,',','.'),2))) + ', ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(PARSENAME(REPLACE(Fruits,',','.'),1)))
    END AS Normalized_Fruits
FROM #Fruits
```

Answer (score 1):

And - just for fun - one more solution calling `XQuery` to the rescue.

```
DECLARE @Fruits TABLE(Fruits VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Fruits (Fruits) VALUES 
    ('banana,apple'),
    ('apple,banana'),
    ('kiwi,jackfruit'),
    ('jackfruit, kiwi');
```

--This is the query

```
SELECT f.*
      ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(f.Fruits,' ',''),',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
           .query('
                   for $f in /x/text()
                   order by $f
                   return <y>{concat(",",$f)}</y>
                  ')
           .value('substring(.,2,1000)','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @Fruits f;
```

By using `for $f in distinct-values(/x/text())` instead of `for $f in /x/text()` we would supress repeating words.

In short:
Your string is converted to XML. This allows for `.query()`, which can deal with `XQuery`. This is very mighty with rather generic issues. The words are sorted and returned with a leading comma. The final `substring()` is needed to cut away the first leading comma.